# <router-link> and JSON questions using Vue.js and Vue Router

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-cli-3

I am creating my design portfolio using Vue CLI 3. I am using `<router-view>` and `<router-link>` to navigate to my different components. The architecture of my website is very simple. I have a home page, about page, work page, and several individual project pages:

- Home

  - About
  - Work

    - Project
    - Project
    - Project

The work page consists of several links that would click through to the individual project pages. The work component is set up like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <projectLink v-for="data in projectLinkJson" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import projectLink from '@/components/projectLink.vue'
import json from '@/json/projectLink.json'

export default {
  name: 'work',
  data(){
    return{
      projectLinkJson: json
    }
  },
  components: {
    projectLink
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm importing JSON to dynamically render the content. The projectLink component is like so:

```
<template>
  <router-link to='/project'>
    <div class="projectLink" v-bind:class="type">
      <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    </div>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'projectLink',
  props: {
    title: String,
    type: String
  }
}
</script>
```

In the component above, you can see that I have a `<router-link>` set to '/project'. In my `routes.js` file, I am just telling this route to go to my project page component. I want to use the project page component as the framework for each of my individual project pages. But how do I do this dynamically? How can I route to the same component for each project, but change the content for each individual project page? Can I do this with JSON, like I'm doing within the work component.

My guess was that I could alter the `<router-link>` to give it a URL query. And then serve the data based on the changing URL query

```
<router-link :to="{ path: 'project', query: { url }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a router-link like so:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'projectDetails', params: { name: projectName }}">
```

I would pass some type of identifier for the project in the params object. In this example I am using name but an id may be more appropriate in your case. I would recommend using a "named" route so you can change url's easier in the future.

I would then make a ProjectDetails.vue page.

I would make an entry in your router file like so:

```
{
    path: "/project/:name",
    name: "projectDetails",
    props: true,
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "ProjectDetails"*/ "../views/ProjectDetails")
},
```

Comment: Kyle, excuse my not knowing anything ha. What is the import line at bottom that references webpackChunkName? I understand everything in your answer other than that part. Thanks!

Comment: Defining the component as an arrow function allows the component to be lazy loaded by the browser. The webpackChunkName tells webpack what to call this "chunk" of code. If you don't use the webpackChunkName comment then webpack will give it a less friendly name.

Comment: That worked for me. My URL is now populating /project/'name' with JSON. Sorry to ask so many questions, but how would I now input JSON data into the new component fields dynamically based on the 'name' value. Almost there!!

Comment: Hey Kyle, just following up here and was curious if you would have a solution? Any time is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the ProjectDetails.vue component you would look up the details of the project by it's name (or id). Typically you would do this in the created lifecycle function.